# How can I recover chef node object from deletion?

Tags: chef-infra

All data had been deleted for some nodes from chef-server (v11) by mistakes. 
Is there a way of recovering node/role objects, `run_list`?

Comment: What data are you talking about? node object?

Comment: yes, it is role and node object

Answer (score 0):

No, no record is kept after deletion unless you had a backup.